# How do the implementation of Eq typeclass function: x == y = not (x /= y) x /= y = not (x == y) work?

Tags: haskell, recursion, typeclass, mutual-recursion

I am reading the [book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures), and it talks about the definition of typeclass `Eq`

There are two functions `==`, `/=` in the Eq, and they are implemented as:

```
  x == y = not (x /= y)  
  x /= y = not (x == y)
```

The book says that they are mutual recursion, the result of the function is in item of another function.

What I don't understand is that I don't see a base case in the mutual recursion, and I don't understand why the functions will stop and return a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With those definitions, the mutual recursion won't stop - it will recurse infinitely. The idea is that you override one of the two definitions with your own base case when implementing the `Eq` typeclass.

So for example if you have a type `data Foo = Bar | Baz` your `Eq` instance could look like this:

```
instance Eq Foo where
  Bar == Bar = True
  Baz == Baz = True
  _   == _   = False
```

Here we only defined `==`, not `/=`, so `/=` will use its default definition `not (x == y)`. However our definition of `==` will not call `/=` back, so its no longer mutually recursive and will terminate without problems.

The reason that `Eq` provides default implementations for both `==` and `/=` is so that you can decide whether you want to provide a definition for `==` or `/=` and you get the other one for free even if you choose `/=`.

Comment: With [my proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7633) -- hopefully to be in the next version of GHC -- you can specify the minimal complete definition of a class in a compiler-checkable way, so that you'd get a warning if you didn't implement either method.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks for your explanation. In fact, there is an explanation in the book just below but I could not realize it exists...